# overloading << operator with ostream is not working. Why?

Tags: c++

I have a small code snippet which tries to overload "<<" operator of std::cout.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const string& str)
{
    out << "overloading" << str << "done";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "string123";
}
```

output: string123.
It seems my overloading function is not being called. Why?

Comment: Maybe because there already *is* [an overload of the output operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) that takes a `std::string`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg More likely, one that accepts `const char*`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The overload which accepts `std::string` is defined in `<string>` header, which is, clearly, not included here.

Comment: Where is `main`'s return type?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: There's nothing stopping `<iostream>` including `<string>` on the OP's implementation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/350805809b04bf7a

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 1) I've never seen an implementation where `<iostream>` includes `<string>` (nor do I see a point for that). 2) If the std version of the overload for `operator<<` for `std::string` was included, OP would get the "redefinition of..." compiler error.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: 1) I just demonstrated one. 2) No, they wouldn't, because the standard one is in namespace `std` and the OP's is not.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, that's right. I forgot about that, my bad. About the link you gave me, where `iostream` includes `string`, I was only going by [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream), which never speaks about it including `string`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: If it didn't, the OP's code wouldn't compile because `string` would not exist. As for that link, that just means that `<iostream>` isn't _guaranteed_ to include `<string>`. That doesn't mean an implementation is prohibited from doing so. You see "accidental" includes all the time, but don't rely on them.

Answer (score 4):

You're basically shooting yourself in the footin your example. You overload `operator<<` for `std::string` type, so you should expect it gets called every time you try to send an "std::string" to `out`, thus causing runtime stack overlow. To make it work, you:

- need to output a `char *` type to `out` in `operator<<` overload, so it doesn't cause infinite recursion
- send an actual `std::string` in `main`.

Here's a working example without runtime stack overflow problem:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const string& str)
{
    out << "overloading" << str.c_str() << "done";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    cout << std::string("string123");
}
```

The output is

```
overloadingstring123done
```

Comment: @user2531608 upvote and answer acceptance is stackoverflow way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're not streaming a `std::string`, but a `const char*`. You can fix that by writing `cout << std::string("string123")` instead ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de0c7cd096c90ac0); although, ew).

Note that there is already such an overload in `<string>`, and your implementation apparently just go happens to include `<string>` through `<iostream>` ([as does mine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/350805809b04bf7a), and as is its prerogative). However, your version (after making the fix above) is a better match since ADL doesn't need to be invoked to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a string type to `<<`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const string& str)
{
    out<<"overloading";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "string123";
    cout << s;
}
```

Note that sending again the string itself in the `<<` definition will make infinite recursion for

```
out << "overloading" << str <<"done"
```

Comment: It does output "overloading" string, but doesn't output "string123"

Comment: @buld0zzr That's right. So? The OP question is about overloading, not how to do some printing example.

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/ your implementation is not an expected behavior for `ostream<<` operator

Comment: @buld0zzr Are you kidding? This is not the issue. Nothing here has  "expected behavior" of general `ostream<<`